# How can I write condition in setState function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I wrote `if` for `title:` in `SetConfirmDialog`, But not work. How can i do it?

```js
<Button
  color={user.active ? "success" : "error"}
  variant="text"
  startIcon={<UserCheck />}
  title={user.active ? "غیر فعال کردن" : "فعال کردن"}
  onClick={() => {
    SetConfirmDialog({
      isOpen: true,
      title: { user.active ? 'کاربر فعال گردد؟' : 'کاربر غیر فعال گردد؟' },
      subTitle: 'شما مطعن هستید که کابر باید فعال گردد؟'
    });
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `title` is a string:

```
SetConfirmDialog({
  isOpen: true,
  title: user.active ? 'کاربر فعال گردد؟' : 'کاربر غیر فعال گردد؟',
  subTitle: 'شما مطعن هستید که کابر باید فعال گردد؟'
});
```